# Get the most recent open date through an SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have trouble with my query to get the most recent email open date.

This is my query:

```
Select distinct (SubscriberKey),EmailAddress, max(OpenTime) as OpenTime
from unique_opens2
WHERE OpenTime > dateadd(d,-90,getdate())
group by SubscriberKey,EmailAddress
```

The unique_opens2 is where I save all the unique email opens per subscriber.

This query works but when I try to add a few filds such as the Jo ID, the email name and the send time, it does'nt work and I get the duplicate key message because bascially, it can't filter.

How should I proceed?

Comment: can you show an example of the query that is showing the error? I get the feeling it is because your grouping/distinct is creating duplicate records compared to your primary key on the DE.

Comment: I would review this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record